# Difference between venture and adventure

Tags: meaning, synonyms

Is there any difference between usage of words *venture* and *adventure*?

Is *venture* a short form usage of *adventure*?

Comment: Have you looked in a dictionary? What did it say about the definitions of the two words? What in those definitions has lead you to be confused about these word's meanings? Please [edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/73787/edit) your question to clarify what you do not understand. In addition you might find it beneficial to read [ask].

Comment: I agree with @Matt.  Otherwise, this question could turn into a misadventure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They have overlapping definitions.

"[Venture](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/adventure)" means:

1. an undertaking, especially a risky or dangerous one
2. a business enterprise or speculation

On the other hand, "[adventure](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/adventure)" can be used to mean:

1. an exciting or very unusual experience
2. a bold, risky undertaking; a hazardous action
3. a business enterprise or speculation

In practice though, I'd say "venture" is now preferred to talk about **business enterprise**. Especially with expressions like "venture capitalist" and "venture company."

The sense of **excitement** and **unusual experience** is also emphasized in the word "adventure," as in the example "an adventure in dining"

Comment: Isn't the first definition of "venture" and the second of "adventure" the same? Does that mean that the two words can be used interchangeably in some context ?

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi as Cool Elf said, if you use adventure, excitement and unusual experience is empathized. Say you're making a trip to a mountain top. You could say both that you're on an _adventure_ to the mountain top and that you're on a _venture_ to the mountain top. The former in this case contains the fact that your travel is risky and dangerous, but it also expresses that you're experiencing excitement and strangeness (positive or negative depending on the tone). The latter on the other hand does not express your feelings towards the trip, only that it is risky.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that *venture* is a verb (*'venture a guess'*) and *adventure* is a noun (*'the adventure of a lifetime'*).

Unfortunately, the waters get muddied because *venture* is, on rare occasions, used as a noun (*'A risky venture'*) and *adventure* is, on even rarer occasions, used as a verb (*'adventuring into new areas'*).

Answer (score 0):

In the sense **risk the loss of...** , yes. According to Oxford dictionary, **venture** comes from late Middle English and is the shortening of adventure.